# Extracting data from nested XML PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have an XML that needs to be inserted into the table. The XML looks something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <pats>
      <pat>
         <id>1</id>
         <pat_maps>
            <pat_map>
               <pgid>100</pgid>
               <pgname>test</pgname>
            </pat_map>
            <pat_map>
               <pgid>101</pgid>
               <pgname>test1</pgname>
            </pat_map>
         </pat_maps>
      </pat>
      <pat>
         <id>2</id>
         <pat_maps>
            <pat_map>
               <pgid>102</pgid>
               <pgname>test2</pgname>
            </pat_map>
         </pat_maps>
      </pat>
      <pat>
         <id>3</id>
         <pat_maps>
            <pat_map>
               <pgid>104</pgid>
               <pgname>test6</pgname>
            </pat_map>
            <pat_map>
               <pgid>105</pgid>
               <pgname>test7</pgname>
            </pat_map>
         </pat_maps>
      </pat>
   </pats>
</root>
```

I want to insert data in the following way

```
ID  pgid    pgname
1   100     test
1   101     test1
2   102     test2
3   104     test6
3   105     test7
```

Tried below but it is applying cross join

```
with x(t) as (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <pats>
..............
..........
      </pat>
   </pats>
</root>'::xml AS t
)
, base_id as (SELECT 
    unnest(xpath('/root/pats/pat/id/text()', t)) AS id
from x
), nested_rec as ( select 
    unnest(xpath('pgid/text()', cat_assn_list)) AS pgid,
    unnest(xpath('pgname/text()', cat_assn_list)) AS pgname
from (select unnest(xpath('/root/pats/pat/pat_maps/pat_map', t)) cat_assn_list from x) q
) 
select base_id.*,nested_rec.* from base_id,nested_rec;

******* output *********
ID  PGID    PGNAME  
"1" "100"   "test"
"1" "101"   "test1"
"1" "102"   "test2"
"1" "104"   "test6"
"1" "105"   "test7"
"2" "100"   "test"
"2" "101"   "test1"
"2" "102"   "test2"
"2" "104"   "test6"
"2" "105"   "test7"
"3" "100"   "test"
"3" "101"   "test1"
"3" "102"   "test2"
"3" "104"   "test6"
"3" "105"   "test7"
```

I haven't found a way, how to nest the XML ID wise and prepare the resultset?.
Is there any other way to convert xml data to table without using XPath function in PostgreSQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: XPATH is the way to go, but I don't understand your problem. What do you mean by "nest the XML" or "prepare the resultset"? Why don't you simply insert your result?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe " nest the XML ID wise and prepare the resultset" mean iterate the ID element in xml and prepare the PGID and PGNAME sub-elements data. Can you check this section "I want to insert data in the following way"  in the description, which is how I need the end-result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does what you want and is a bit shorter:

```
select (xpath('/pat/id/text()', d.pat))[1]::text::int as id,
       (xpath('/pat_map/pgid/text()', m.map))[1]::text::int as pgid,
       (xpath('/pat_map/pgname/text()', m.map))[1]::text as pgname
from x 
  cross join unnest(xpath('/root/pats/pat', x.t)) as d(pat)
  cross join unnest(xpath('/pat/pat_maps/pat_map', d.pat)) as m(map)
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=87c795f5d3f4ec4aa81963c0316d4b36)

With a more modern Postgres version, you could use `xmltable()`:

```
select d.*
from x
  cross join xmltable ('/root/pats/pat/pat_maps/pat_map' 
                       passing t 
                       columns 
                        id integer path '../../id',
                        pgid integer path 'pgid', 
                        pgname text path 'pgname') as d
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working in Postgres 9.5 version. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=ca709d075ea3a974953dba44c04c316f

Comment: @Mahesh: ah, 9.5 requires an absolute path. See my edit